# Failing on checking on existence of xml attribute in linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I have an list of "IEnumerable " all of the same elements: "elem1", that I got by

```
IEnumerable <XElement> childList = 
                    from el in sessionXML.DescendantsAndSelf().Elements("elem1")
                    select el;
```

childList:

```
<elem1 att1= "..." att2= "..."> </elem1>
<elem1 att1= "..." att2= "..." att3 = "..."> </elem1>
<elem1 att1> </elem1>
```

Not all of the elements have the same attributes. I'm trying to check the existence of att3, if so, I'd like to print this element, when I did below code, it still gives me a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error:

```
 foreach (XElement e in childList)
        {
            //Check if attribute "target" exists
            if (e.Attribute("att3").Value != null)
            {
                Console.writeLine(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking `.Value` or any other property on a `null` object  is illegal:

```
if (e.Attribute("att3") != null)
```

Comment: This would be the equivalent of a null pointer exception in languages like C right?